# Rails 4 : undefined method `increment!'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to fix a Redmine plugin written for Redmine 2.5 to work with Redmine 3 which uses Rails 4. When it executes the following code:

```
project_issue_key.increment!(:last_issue_number)
```

I get the following exception:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `increment!' for #<ProjectIssueKey::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f65f52cf648>):
```

I am thinking that the increment! method has been deprecated. How is this done in Rails 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `increment!` on the object, not ActiveRecord::Relation. Something like `ProjectIssueKey.first.increment!(:last_issue_number)`.

`increment!` is still present in Rails 4 , check these [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/increment%21).

Comment: That code is in the ProjectIssueKey class and it project_issue_key is set to project_issue_key = where(project_key: key).lock(true). The code previously assigned it to project_issue_key = find_by_project_key(key, :lock => true) but it erros out on Rails 4 so I had to change it.

Apparently using where() returns a relation. What is the new way to do a find_by_ in Rails 4 with lock enabled?

Comment: You have to change it like this `find_by(project_key: key, lock: true)`

Comment: Thanks for helping out adam, lock is actually not a field. It is a transaction lock. This part is inside a transaction do block. I can get it to work if I do a find_by_project_key but I am not sure if will do a database lock which it needs to do to prevent the generation of duplicate numbers.

Comment: Oh sure. Sorry, I messed that up for you :D.

Comment: But when using find it should be used like this `Account.lock.find(1)
` check this out http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html

Comment: Great! Thank you. It is working now. I absolutely know nothing about Rails but looks like I got it working with a little help on that thing.